# How to update the APN Certification as the new developer

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I searched everywhere but couldn't find the right answer. I'm a new developer in a company, not natively IOS developer btw, they developed an app via contractor and the guy left last year and now APNs certificate is expired and we need a new one. I have a developer account (paid one) and my email is listed as Admin in App Store Connect. In my developer account I dont have this company's APP as expected because it was created by another developer. Now with my current developer account and using my admin rights in App Store Connect I want to create a new certificate for APNs, is this even possible? Please guide me I'm totally lost! I already mailed Apple but no response so far!
Thank you

Comment: Please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) App Store questions fall under this guidance.